# appearanceWhenContainedIn not working as expected

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uiappearance

I'm using iOS's UIAppearanceProxy to customize the look of my app.

In most of the app, I want the navBar to have one background image. In one specific section of the app, I want the navBar to have a different background image.

Here's what I'm doing in `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"navbar_bg1"]
                                   forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];

[[UINavigationBar appearanceWhenContainedIn:[DiscoverViewController class], nil] setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"navbar_bg2"]                                                   forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

I would like to keep all my appearance code in one place instead of overriding the navBar in a specific view controller.

Also helpful to know is that my app is structured with a TabBarController, where each tab controls a NavigationController which owns a subclassed ViewController, like DiscoverViewController above.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As you just stated, the navigation bar is not contained in the `DiscoverViewController` in your hierarchy; rather, both are contained in a navigation controller. One way to keep the appearance code centralized is to create an empty subclass of `UINavigationController` and instantiate that instead of `UINavigationController` in the relevant place (whether that's a nib or storyboard or just programmatically). Then, to style child elements, get their appearance proxy "when contained in" `DiscoveryNavigationController` or what have you. I've used this method with good results in the past.